# Salaries Differences between the departments

Tags: mysql

This question is from Strata Scratch:Write a query that calculates the difference between the highest salaries found in the marketing and engineering departments. Output just the absolute difference in salaries.

Tables: db_employee, db_dept

I don't know i am not getting correct output:

```
SELECT
  ABS(MAX(CASE 
           WHEN dept.department = 'marketing' THEN emp.salary 
           ELSE 0 
         END) - 
      MAX(CASE 
           WHEN dept.department = 'engineering' THEN emp.salary 
           ELSE 0 
         END)) AS salary_difference 
FROM db_employee emp 
JOIN db_dept dept ON emp.department_id = dept.id
```

Comment: Your query seems to be doing what you are describing, e.g. we can think of tables and data that your query would work with. If it doesn't, you would need to provide your table structure, sample data, the output you get and the output you expect. The problem might be in some details specific to your situation, e.g. the departments might be defined case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a WHERE clause might help filter the which looks for emps in the mentioned departments.
The possible reason you are facing an error could be because of the conditional aggregator is not being used correctly.
Check the query and I hope this helps.

```
SELECT ABS(MAX(CASE WHEN dept.department = 'marketing' THEN emp.salary ELSE 0 END) - 
               MAX(CASE WHEN dept.department = 'engineering' THEN emp.salary ELSE 0 END)) AS salary_difference 
    FROM db_employee emp 
    JOIN db_dept dept ON emp.department_id = dept.id
    WHERE dept.department IN ('marketing', 'engineering');
```